# Adding new column in R based on start and end times for each unique value of a third column

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to define a new variable *word_duration*, calculated by subtracting the first *start_time* from the last *end_time* of each *syllable* for each unique *word*.

Here is a minimal example, and how I want the data-frame to look with the new *word_duration* column:

```
df <- data.frame("word" = c("each", "each", "unique", "unique", "word", "unique", "unique"), 
                 "syllable" = c("ea", "ch", "u", "nique", "word", "u", "nique"),
                "start_time" = c(41.48, 42.95, 43.49, 43.95, 44.07, 44.12, 44.19), 
                "end_time" = c(42.95, 43.49, 43.95, 44.07, 44.12, 44.19, 44.23))

    word syllable start_time end_time word_duration
1   each       ea      41.48    42.95 2.01
2   each       ch      42.95    43.49 2.01
3 unique        u      43.49    43.95 0.58
4 unique    nique      43.95    44.07 0.58
5   word     word      44.07    44.12 0.05
6 unique        u      44.12    44.19 0.11
7 unique    nique      44.19    44.23 0.11
```

Example of how the new variable should be defined:

- e.g. the *word* "unique" occurs twice in the data-frame and has two syllables
- the first syllable of the first "unique" starts at 43.49 seconds and the second syllable of "unique" ends at 44.07
- so the *word_duration* of the *word* "unique" is 44.07-43.49 = 0.58 seconds

So, the individual *word_duration*s should be 2.01, 0.58, 0.05, 0.11, but I'm afraid I'd need some for-loops or something to define *word_duration*. It's also complicated by the fact that each word occurs multiple times in the data-frame, so it needs to be worked out row by row. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `split` by a change in *word* saved in `i`, get the `diff` of `range` and `unsplit` the result to store it in *df*.

```
i <- c(0, cumsum(df$word[-1] != head(df$word, -1)))
df$word_duration <-  unsplit(lapply(split(df[c("start_time", "end_time")], i),
 function(x) diff(range(x))), i)
df
#    word syllable start_time end_time word_duration
#1   each       ea      41.48    42.95          2.01
#2   each       ch      42.95    43.49          2.01
#3 unique        u      43.49    43.95          0.58
#4 unique    nique      43.95    44.07          0.58
#5   word     word      44.07    44.12          0.05
#6 unique        u      44.12    44.19          0.11
#7 unique    nique      44.19    44.23          0.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```r
library(zoo) # for na.locf
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(
    "word" = c("each", "each", "unique", "unique", "word", "unique", "unique"),
    "syllable" = c("ea", "ch", "u", "nique", "word", "u", "nique" ),
    "start_time" = c(41.48, 42.95, 43.49, 43.95, 44.07, 44.12, 44.19),
    "end_time" = c(42.95, 43.49, 43.95, 44.07, 44.12, 44.19, 44.23)
) %>% as.data.table

df[, lead := word != shift(word,fill=TRUE) ]
df[ lead == TRUE , word_duration := shift( start_time,type="lead") - start_time  ]

## fix the last word:
last_end_time <- last( df$end_time )
df[ lead == TRUE & is.na(word_duration), word_duration := last_end_time - start_time ]

## make sure NA's are filled with the common word_duration for the syllables
df[ , word_duration := na.locf( word_duration ) ]
```

It identifies when each word starts, then fetches the start point of the next starting word, and uses that as the end point, as that seems to be valid in the data you provided.

It then manually fixes the last word as that didn't have a next word to get the start from.